# c -language dynamic memory

Tags: c

hi thanx every body for their support but no one provide me the required information now i try to did that program like this

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int **a,i,j;
    system("clear");

    a=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*5);

    for (i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        a[i]= malloc(sizeof(int)*3);

        for (j=0; j<3; j++)
        {
            printf("\nplease enter the [%d][%d] location = ",i,j);
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
        }
    }


    for (i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<3; j++)
        {
            printf("\nthe value enter  enter the [%d][%d] location = ",i,j);
            printf("%d",a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    free(a);
    return ;
}
```

i complied it on compilation it shows warnig which is following

```
c:8: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
```

on running the program it take 15 value from user but it did not show the value entered by user
can anybody explain what i'm doing wrong ,can any body explain me the concept of double pointer & dynamic memory allocation

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Formatting fixed, please avoid to post again code like that, it hurts everyone's eyes.

Comment: Possible duplicate (same user): [c - dynamic memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853929/c-dynamic-memory)

Comment: you should work on improving your original question rather than duplicating it - also try reading the answers to your previous question a little more carefully

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, the memory allocation in your code is incorrect. The first `malloc` should look as follows

```
a = (int **) malloc(sizeof(int *) * 5);
```

Your `a` is `int **`, as you declared it. You are casting the result of `malloc` to `int *`. `int *` and `int **` are those incompatible types the compiler is warning you about. To avoid such errors in the future, get rid of the bad habit of using types in statements. Types in C belong in *declarations*. *Statements* should be as type-independent as possible. The above `malloc` call would look much better this way

```
a = malloc(5 * sizeof *a);
```

Note: no cast, no types mentioned. The second `malloc` would look as follows

```
a[i] = malloc(3 * sizeof *a[i]);
```

I hope you see the pattern in accordance with which these `malloc` calls are built.

You also forget to deallocate memory for individual sub-arrays in your program (`a[i]` memory is never deallocated, while `a` memory is).

As for the program not showing the entered values... The first problem with broken `malloc` call is serious enough to prevent your program from working, but it still might appear to "work" on some platforms. On such platforms it should show the values. Are you sure you are not simply missing the output?

Answer (score 3):

This code has several errors. First of all, the warning refers to the fact that you're trying to assign a pointer to integer (`int *`) to a variable (`a`) which is a pointer to a pointer to integer (`int **`), which you actually want to use as an array of arrays.

So, first correction, at line 8 it's not

```
a=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*5);
```

but it is

```
a=(int**)malloc(sizeof(int *)*5);
```

(that cast *in C* isn't strictly necessary, but being a C++ programmer I prefer to keep it like that)

Notice that also the expression in the `sizeof` changed, since what you want to allocate is not the space for five integers, but the space for five *pointers* to integers.

Then, at the end of the application, you're `free`ing just the space allocated with the first `malloc`, while you made other five allocations (one for each row). Thus, you could do the deallocation in the last cycle, just after displaying each row.

```
for (i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    for (j=0; j<3; j++)
    {
        printf("\nthe value enter  enter the [%d][%d] location = ",i,j);
        printf("%d",a[i][j]);
    }
    free(a[i]);
    a[i]=NULL;
}
free(a);
a=NULL;
```

Remember: for each `malloc` or `calloc`, you have to have it's corresponding `free`, otherwise you're leaking memory.

Here, after each deallocation, I set the corresponding pointer to `NULL` to throw away those old, now-invalid, pointers. Somebody say that this behavior can mask double-frees (since `free(NULL)` doesn't produce errors), but IMHO this is better than the alternative

One important detail: you're not checking the return value of `malloc`, which is quite bad. It's extremely unlikely that in such small programs allocations may fail, but, nonetheless, it's good practice to *always* check if the return value of `malloc` is `NULL`, and, in this case, handle the situation gracefully, usually releasing all the resources and shutting down the application.

By the way, `system("clear");` is ugly. You should use the platform-specific way to clean the screen, even better if enclosed in a function; on Linux with normal (X3.64) terminal emulators something like this could be ok:

```
void ClearScreen()
{
    fputs("\x1B[2J\x1B[1;1H", stdout);
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`a` points to an array of `int` pointers. So each element of that array is of type `int*` not `int`. So you should be using `sizeof(int*)`.

this

```
a = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*5);
```

should be

```
a = malloc(sizeof(int*)*5);
                   ^
```

As [malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/malloc/) in C returns a `void` pointer and C implicitly casts from and to `void*` there is no need of a cast.

You might want to read this:

[**Should I explicitly cast malloc()'s return value?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953112/should-i-explicitly-cast-mallocs-return-value)

Comment: You should mention why you got rid of that ugly unneeded cast.

Answer (score 1):

```
   a = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*5);
     ^
     |
Warning due to this
```

`a` is a pointer to pointer to `int` i.e `int **`.

You are casting `malloc()`'s return value to `int*` and then assigning it to `int**` so the implicit conversion from `int*` to `int**` generates the warning. Moreover it should be `sizeof(int *)` inside first `malloc()` [as you are trying to allocate memory for a two dimensional array].

Try this :

```
a=(int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*5);
```

Comment: You're forgetting the missing frees.

Answer (score 0):

On line 6 you should have

```
a = (int**) malloc(sizeof(int*) * 5));
```